# how can I dynamically add a filter by bytecode tech?

Tags: filter, bytecode

I want to improve my web application by using the spring-session, but I need to avoid changing the source code. How can I implement spring-session with help of bytecode tech such as ASM etc?

Comment: Why do you need to avoid changing the source code? It sounds like you're violating a license agreement.

Comment: My team try to implement the spring-session to web-application which deployed on tomcat, so the app will store session on redis. However, to implement the spring-session, I need to place the RepositoryFilter(class of spring-session) at the top of other filter. I am aware that  I could modified the web.xml to do that, but the team leader wishes we can do it smoother. Maybe implement spring-session by bytecode-plugin, so there would be less modification for original web-app source code( it is a pile of old stuff, nobody wants to modify it).

Comment: It's always a better choice to modify the source code and rebuild than to rely on bytecode modification. Hacking bytecode makes your app much less maintainable.

Comment: I agree that, but I'm not at the position to decide which method to apply. Although I suggested rather to modify the source code than using bytecode tech, decision were made by my boss. He had his consideration, so I had to figure out a way to make my bytecode plugin. I checked the servlet api (including 2.5, 3.0)and JSR340,etc. I still cannot find out an appropriate way to do the interception, even do not know which class to take care.